# passing source to latex on command line

Tags: scripts, command-line

In a shell script, I'm doing things like

```
pdflatex <<- EOT
\def\something{a}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\something
\end{document}
EOT
```

which works as expected. However, when specifying `-interaction=nonstopmode`, latex quits with

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
**entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-16>
! Emergency stop.
<*> \def\something{a}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

The log file is not much enlightening either:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex 2023.6.21)  4 JUL 2023 10:59
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\def\something{a}
! Emergency stop.
<*> \def\something{a}
                     
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nonstopmode says don't accept user input from stdin and `<<- EOT` is user input on stdin so it stops with an error as specified

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I see my misconception. Is there any way to say 'read input as usual, but don't prompt me in case of an error?'. Otherwise, I guess I'll have to use intermediate files.

Comment: scrollmode is perhaps what you are looking for

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nonstopmode` says don't accept user input from stdin and `<<- EOT` is user input on stdin so it stops with an error as specified.

`scrollmode` is perhaps what you are looking for.